# How to add DataTemplates to ScatterViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I'm trying to build a kind of Wizard with a ScatterViewItem. In the lower area are buttons for Next, Back and Cancel. When pressing on the Next or Back button the upper part should show the next 'page'. I've tried using a DataTemplate, but the DataTemplate is not showing in the upper area. I get only a blank area.
I'm still new to WPF and Surface and maybe try something that did not work. May you have better ideas.
Here's the code:

```
<s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="LoadProject">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Name="lbl_Database" Content="Database" />
                    <s:SurfaceTextBox Name="txt_Database"/>
                    <Label Name="lbl_Project" Content="Project" />
                    <s:SurfaceTextBox Name="txt_Project"/>
    </StackPanel>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="LoadProject">
</s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>

<s:ScatterView>
    <s:ScatterViewItem Width="300" Height="300">      
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ItemsControl x:Name="DynamicArea" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LoadProject}" Grid.Column="1">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
                <s:SurfaceButton Name="btn_Next" Content="Next" />
                <s:SurfaceButton Name="btn_Back" Content="Back" />
                <s:SurfaceButton Name="btn_Cancel" Content="Cancel" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </s:ScatterViewItem>
</s:ScatterView>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the ItemsPanelTemplate to a StackPanel? Grid is a tough one to crack since you would need to bind the Grid.Row/Column through an ItemsControl's ItemContainerStyle. Also - you don't set the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl anywhere here. Do you do it in code behind?